# batch file syntax to rename excel file

Tags: batch-file

We have dashboard application which accepts the file with name having date in MMDDYYYY format

Example as below, last part is MMDDYYYY format

‘Canada_report~D~05032013.xls’

There are reports scheduled through one of reporting tool which generates exce lfile with YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS format and there is no other format available apart from this.

Example as below, last part is YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS format

'Canada_report~D~2013-05-03-05-14-26.XLS’

I am looking for batch Script which can rename **all excel files** which are in particular directory on network location geneated through my reporting tool to the same format which is required for dashboard

Canada_report~D~2013-05-03-05-14-26.XLS -> ‘Canada_report~D~05032013.xls’
America_report~D~2013-06-13-05-14-26.XLS -> ‘America_report~D~06132013.xls’

Appreciate any help regarding this.. I dont have any exposure to batch scripting..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Google `Advanced Renamer`.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,* delims=-~" %i in ('dir /b *.xls') do echo %i~%j~%l%m%k.xls

input:
Canada_report~D~2013-05-03-05-14-26.XLS

output:
Canada_report~D~05032013.xls
```

Comment: Thanks Jones--I have followed below steps but renaming is not working--1) created excel file in M:\Test with name as Canada_report~D~2013-05-03-05-14-26.xls 
2) created batch file with below code                                         for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,* delims=-~" %i in ('M:\Test *.xls') do echo %i~%j~%l%m%k.xls

Comment: On command line use one % like %j, in batch file use %% like %%j.

Comment: did not get you..i am looking for renaming of file in my directory

Answer (score 0):

using the Scott's code:

```
for %%F in (*.xls) do (
   for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,* delims=-~" %%i in ("%%F") do ren "%%F" "%%i~%%j~%%l%%m%%k.xls"
)
```

Comment: I think Scott is intended not to give the actual command, but just giving key part and let OP finish the rest...

Comment: can you explain..i would like to learn..like what exactly tokens doing etc..also above solution is not working

Comment: understood code somewhat..but still not sure why below code not working                                                          for %%F in (M:\Test\*.xls) do (
   for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,* delims=~" %%i in ("%%F") do rename "%%F" "%%i~%%j~%%l%%m%%k.xls"
)

Comment: what is the output of ` for %%F in (M:\Test*.xls) do echo %%F` ?

Comment: Please see below error from CMD..without echo, I dont see any error but renaming not working                   C:\Users\npatil17> for %F in (M:\Test*.xls) do ( for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,* delims=~" %i in ("%F") do rename "%F" "%i~%j~%l%m%k.xls" ) do @echo %~F
do was unexpected at this time.